# Returning response string to setup Webhook

Tags: php, webhooks

I'm trying to integrate PHP Webhooks with the Onfleet API. 
The Documentation says I must return a simple string response

https://docs.onfleet.com/reference#create-webhook
Here is my code

```
$input = file_get_contents("php://input");

if (isset($input)) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $input->check;
}
```

I keep receiving the error "Value received in response does not match the value we sent you"

Comment: have you got solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' && isset($_GET['check']))
{
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $_GET['check'];
}
```

Comment: I tested, but its not working.. have any other option ?

Comment: are you killing the script? According to the documentation you must not return anything else. `exit;` after `echo $_GET['check'];`. You must also return with HTTP status code 200